# Error with mixitup filtering on pages that don't have filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

On my homepage I have mixitup working using this:

```
var containerEl = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
    var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
        selectors: {
            control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
        },
        load: {
            filter: '.engagement-ceremony'
        }
    });
```

I got this from their website. It works fine, but the moment I go to another page I'm getting this error in console:
`Uncaught Error: [MixItUp] An invalid selector or element reference was passed to the mixitup factory function` and it's causing my other js on the page to break.

I thought I'd try this instead to see what happens:

```
var mixer = mixitup('.gallery-container', {
        selectors: {
            control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
        },
        load: {
            filter: '.engagement-ceremony'
        }
    });
```

But then I got this error: `Uncaught Error: [MixItUp] The provided selector yielded no container element`.

I'm stumped as to why this would error this way.

**EDIT**
So the only way I could get this to work properly without errors is to take this part of the mixitup script and load it onto my homepage conditionally using `php`. A hacky fix that bothers me, but the only way it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Gallery Filtering
    var containerEl = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
    var mixer;

    if (containerEl) {
        mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
             selectors: {
                 control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
             },
             load: {
                 filter: '.engagement-ceremony'
             }
        });
    }
```

I had to wrap the script in a `if` statement.